# What to do when being Lawful and being Good are mutually exclusive?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, alignment

Do any of the D&D guidebooks or rulebooks, from any edition, state what should be done when a Lawful Good character is faced with a dilemma where "being Good" would require breaking the law, and "being Lawful" would require not "being Good?"

Comment: It would be best to confine this question to a given edition as the alignment axis and treatment has some variation across editions.

Comment: It would probably help to give an example of when this would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In every edition, the character would make a decision according to their personality, preferences, and circumstances.

Having an alignment is just the beginning; *How* a character acts within their alignment, and *why and how* they violate it, are what makes adherence to an alignment interesting. In much the same way as playing any character torn between two conflicting ideals or beliefs is interesting, really.

Comment: While I agree with you, particularly in paragraph 2, the written consequences and impacts of alignment choices vary somewhat across editions, with the latest 5e having a description that allows more variation in practice than some other editions ... though the DM's judgment will color any and all cases .

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I left off including edition-specific details because I didn't know which edition the OP is having a problem in. I'll happily add the edition-specific elaboration once I find out. (Provided it's an edition I know about, of course. If it's one of the ones I don't have access to, I'll delete this answer once someone posts an edition-specific one.)

Comment: Good plan, hope the querent returns to clarify.